# Free printer for printing to PNG (or SVG)

Tags: windows, printing, png, svg

Is there a good free printer driver for printing something to PNG (or maybe even SVG) for Windows (I use 7 64bit)? I've got this site with some statistics and it displays this cool graph. It's got an embed feature, but that's using flash. I want to put this graph on my blog, but I don't want to use flash for mobile browser reasons. This site also supports printing the graph. So what I thought I would do is print the graph to a PNG or SVG file and use the picture.

I've been searching around and I can't really find anything good or I'm just not typing in the correct keywords. Either way if you know of a good printer-to-file please share. Or if you see any other way.

BTW: Can smart phones even handle SVGs?

Comment: Print to pdf, then [`pdf2svg`](https://github.com/jalios/pdf2svg-windows)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try [PDFCreator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfcreator/), it's free/opensource and allows saving as SVG, PDF etc...

Yes, most smartphones can handle svg, the browser on the iphone does for example, and if you install [Opera Mini](http://mini.opera.com/) (available for most phones) you can view svg just fine. [Opera Mobile](http://www.opera.com/mobile/next/) and the mobile version of Firefox for Android also supports SVG. The exception is the default browser on Android 2.3 and below, which doesn't support SVG currently.

Comment: Beware, PDFCreator now includes InstallMonetizer which is pretty nasty malware. Maybe try [Image Printer](http://code-industry.net/imageprinter.php)?

Comment: And slows down computer: One of the svchost's process miraculously starts swallowing RAM and machine becomes unusable.

Comment: I tried at leas ten tools but PDF24 seems to be the best: https://en.pdf24.org/ seems

Comment: ImagePrinter is not free (€ 38,-), prints large watermark across image

Answer (score 3):

Print to PostScript then use either Cairo or ImageMagick to convert it to PNG or SVG.